# How to force tap on UIButton using RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, testing, rx-swift

This is how I subscribe for tap action on `UIButton`:

```
_ = mainView.loginButton.rx.tap.subscribe { _ in
    //this is not called at all
}
```

and now I need to force that action to check if my dependencies work great, but subscribe handler is not called.

```
func testRouterDidCallWithError() {
    let view = LoginView()
    let controller = LoginViewController(view: view)
    controller.loadView()
    view.loginButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside) //here is the point
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works ("ReactiveX/RxSwift" ~> 4.0)

```
someButton.rx.tap
        .bind {
            debugPrint("button tapped")
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Somewhere else

```
someButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
```